# Accessing Raw Encrypted Https Response In C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, encryption

I want to save the encrypted raw https response so that later I can prove the sender of the response. Is this possible to do with any of the built-in libraries in ASP.NET?

Or should I ask for the corresponding party to explicitly encrypt their response regardless of the use of the SSL, so that I can decrypt the response string myself using their public key?

Answer (score 1):

Using HTTPS/SSL/TLS does not by itself authenticate the sender unless you always require client authentication.
If you are not in a position to enforce that, a variant on your second option would be in order: require the corresponding party to explicitly sign the message with his/her private key. If you are able to decrypt the message with their public key, this proves their identity.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you exactly mean by "always requiring client authentication"? Why is ssl short on authenticating the sender?

Comment: The primary effect of SSL is to encrypt the connection between server. In the process you get authentication of the server by means of the certificate that is installed on the server (that certificate is presented in the setup fase of the ssl-connection).
SSL does not necessarily require the client to authenticate itself, although the web-server can be configured to require a client certificate for a connection. To enable this, you need to be able to set the server configuration.

Comment: Not sure if this is right. OP said "response" not "request." The issuer of an https response is always authenticated. I agree you need a client cert to authenticate the issuer of the *request*.